# Why doesn't headerTransparent and custom param headerTitle work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm working with React Native and React Navigation. Recently I stumbled across a case where I wanted my header to be transparent using `headerTransparent: true`, while also being able to display the `headerTitle` dynamically based on `route.params`. However, it seems like the headerTitle defaults back to the name of the screen component. Why is this and what's the best workaround?

```js
<Items.Screen
name = "Modal"
component = {
    Modal
}
options = {
    (({ route }) => ({
        title: route.params.title
    }), {
        headerTransparent: true
    })
} />
```

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("Modal", { 
  title: title,
})}>
  // Code here.
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, it should look something like this:

```
// ...
<Item.Screen
   name="Modal"
   component={Modal}
   options={({route}) => ({
      title: route.params.title,
      headerTransparent: true,
   })}
/>
// ...
```

---

The reason why your code does partly work (Setting the transparency to true) is because of the way the comma operator works.

> The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

That's why the object setting the transparency on the right is returned, but the object setting the title isn't.

Comment: Ah, missed that one! That worked super well, thanks!